# Can ExFat files saved in dup mode be opened and readable on a mac running Mojave 10.14.6?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, usb, exfat

I have a hard drive I am using in a 7 writer DVD duplicating machine. I upload DVD's to the hard drive and then print new copies of the DVD's on the blank DVD's in the 7 writers directly from the HDD. The machine doesn't work anymore, so I want to take out the HDD and put it into a USB 2.0 or 3.0 cover and be able to plug it into my computer and play the DVD's. I'm currently using MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.6.

The technician said the format of the HDD was EXFAT and on his computer (Windows) the files were only numbered and named 'dup'. He said it was duplicating format and couldn't be opened. He did not try to open them, he just said it wouldn't open and I couldn't use them.

These 60 + videos are very important for me to save.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Does anyone know if this HDD's dup files may have another format connected or within them and can be saved and used with my computer?
Any way to tell?

He put the HDD back into the machine, btw.

Comment: I think the way to tell would be to put it in a USB enclosure & see what the Mac thinks of it. ExFAT itself isn't a problem - the issue might be how the duplicator's firmware/OS dealt with file names vs file contents.

Comment: And if you can find a link to the duplicator you are using maybe we can help you find some info on what format those files are. They *could* be some odd one-off binary format, it could also be a plain Jane MPEG-2 file. Details on the duplicator would help...

Comment: Thank you. The duplicator is a TECH-COM company duplicator. The writers are SATA. The HDD is a Seagate 240 or 260G. It's about 7-8 years old.

Comment: Any other info needed? I'm not tech savvy but I can find out if this is not what you need.

Comment: I searched the .dup file format… apparently it's been used so frequently no-one knows what it ought to be. It is quite possibly a proprietary format [it was never intended to be seen by any OS other than the hardware device]. I'd try contacting the manufacturer [who seem to be a small Indian device builder] & see if they can give you details.

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin. FIrst I will call them and ask about the card and what the specs are for saving in that format and see what they say. Yes, it is a small Indian company, and it's getting smaller. I'm in India, so that was my option.